# How to differentiate between google hangout event and custom event using youtube iOS SDK in an iOS app?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Issue:
I am not able to differentiate Google hangout event and custom event.

I checked the JSON response too. Both are coming with type `youtube#liveBroadcast`. Please let me know which field needs to be monitored to differentiate. How to differentiate Google hangout event and custom event using Youtube iOS SDK in an iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

Refer with this support page about [Stream now, Quick and Custom Live Event Types](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853848?hl=en). Stream now lets you create a live stream in a few easy steps. **Events lets you choose between Quick(Hangouts) and Custom.**

- Quick will create a Hangout On Air with all the standard Hangout On Air features, including quick-start streaming right from your laptop.
- Custom will create a [YouTube Live Event](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853700) where you control your event production and manage your own encoding settings using your preferred platform.

You may check the table on the given link above for more information.